# Web - Update app content?

Tags: ios, xml, json, web

I have a simple question and I could not find a good answer on every search I've made. I wanted to make an app about a company that helps poor people and children with problems. They asked me if I could do an app that would show their latest news and campaigns, and, of course, I said I would do it for free. But I'm kind of a begginer, and I don't know how I should retrieve the news from their website (or twitter) to my app. I've heard of JSON and XML, but I don't know if that would do it. I want an app that would have all the news up-to-date, can anyone please give me some advice and help me? Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have an RSS feed, you could write an app that pulls down the feed, parses it and displays each entry in a table row. You should be able to find plenty of examples on http://github.com to help you.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, every entry in a table row, although, they do not have an RSS feed...

Comment: They need to provide you some way to get the data.

Comment: well, they are rebuilding their website, maybe I could parse the news via twitter? or would apple reject? thanks for the help so far!

Comment: If they post all their news on twitter, you probably could.

Comment: Ok. Thank's for all your answers. Now, one last question, could I pass data from a blog to an app? Would you recommend via JSON or XLM? Once again, Thank you!

Comment: Either would work. A lot of blog software come with RSS feeds built in which provide XML. I would probably start there.